# How do I select pandas rows based on duplicate column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a pandas df which looks like this:

```
+--------+-----------+--------
|Col1    | Col2      |Col3      |
|--------+-----------+----------+
|75      |  84       |    A     | 
|84      |   68      |    B     |                
|75      |   84      |    C     |
|75      |   84      |    A     |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

I want the output to be

```
+--------+-----------+--------
|Col1    | Col2      |Col3      |
|--------+-----------+----------+
|75      |  84       |    A     | 
|75      |  84       |    C     |
```

i.e. wherever the values of Col1 and Col 2 are the same but Col 3 is different.
I have tried

```
df[df.duplicated(['ID'], keep=False)]
```

But this does not identify duplicates based on only 2 column similarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all duplicates by `Col1` and `Col2` and then remove duplicates per all columns by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df[df.duplicated(['Col1', 'Col2'], keep=False)].drop_duplicates()
print (df)
   Col1  Col2 Col3
0    75    84    A
2    75    84    C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [288]: df[df.duplicated(['Col1', 'Col2'], keep=False)].drop_duplicates()
Out[288]: 
   Col1  Col2 Col3
0    75    84    A
2    75    84    C
```